# RestFB: Unable to get post specific to a keyword using restFb api from facebook

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using RestFb to fetch posts for specific keyword. I am using below code for doing the same.

```
Connection<Post> publicSearch = facebookClient.fetchConnection("search", 
Post.class, Parameter.with("q", "ferrari"),Parameter.with("type", "post"));
```

The error facing is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: 
Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: An unknown error has 
occurred. (code 1, subcode null) at 
com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionFo
rTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1196) at 
com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary
(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1111)   at 
com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookCl
ient.java:1045) at 
com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:958) at 
com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:921) at 
com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchConnection(DefaultFacebookClient.java:378)
 at com.XXXXXXXX.facebook.FacebookSource.main(FacebookSource.java:69)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Graph API docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> Public Post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

This endpoint is deprecated since more than one year, and no longer usable since 1st May 2015.

Comment: Thanks Tobi for yout reply. But what can be the alternative for the same ? Can u please suggest something?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no alternative. Facebook deactivated this functionality.